# Rich text to image in QT

Tags: qt, qpainter

In my application , have a [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) dialog that accepts Rich Text Input. I need to convert this input in to an image for some purpose .

If it was Plain text i could use DrawText associated with the [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) class . But Rich text cannot be dealt the same way as we don't know the formatting done.

Any suggestions on how to convert ?

Comment: Classes derived from QWidget are able to draw themselves using the [QWidget::render()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render) method.  Haven't tried it myself.  But hopefully it works even if the widget is hidden, so you could pick an arbitrary rectangular size for a copy of the widget without disturbing your input (if you needed).  Don't know whether QTextEdit would insist on filling the background or be able to draw transparently, either.  But it's a start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `QTextEdit::document` + [`QTextDocument::drawContents`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#drawContents). You don't need any hacks with rendering widgets, as proposed by other authors, because there may be some problems with anti-aliasing settings.

Comment: Try to path dimension of an image to `drawContents` method. And, please, post it as a SSCCE. And use directly `myTextEdit->document()->drawContents()` instead of your code overhead.

Answer (score 5):

You can grab the content of your QTextEdit in the following way:

```
QTextEdit te("This is a rich text");
te.resize(100, 100);
QPixmap pix = QPixmap::grabWidget (&te, te.rect());
pix.save("test.png");
```

Comment: Grab widget retrieves only the part of text that is visible on screen . Hence if the TextEdit has has multiple paragraphs (scrolling enabled short textbox) - this solution would not be applicable right ?

Comment: Yes. You may try to grab viewport. Or check my solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, as also stated in the comments, you can use the widget's `render` method to draw the widget contents into a pixmap:

```
void saveImage(QTextEdit* te) {
    QPixmap pixmap(te->size());
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);

    te->render(&painter);
    pixmap.save("test.png");
}
```

This is essentially what the `QPixmap::grabWidget()` method does internally.

Comment: same with rendering . Render retrieves only the part of text that is visible on screen . Hence if the TextEdit has has multiple paragraphs (scrolling enabled short textbox) - only the visible part of the text will be rasterized to an image along with the scroll bar